# Форматирование даты по маске

Tags: javascript, дата

Символы маски:

- yy – год в 2 цифры
- yyyy – год в 4 цифры
- M – месяц в числовом виде без лидирующего нуля
- MM – месяц в числовом виде в 2 цифры
- MMM – месяц в виде аббревиатуры
- MMMM – месяц в виде полного имени
- d – число без лидирующего нуля
- dd – число в 2 цифры
- H – часы в 24-часовом формате без лидирующего нуля
- HH – часы в 24-часовом формате в 2 цифры
- h – часы в 12-часовом формате без лидирующего нуля
- hh – часы в 12-часовом формате в 2 цифры
- m – минуты без лидирующего нуля
- mm – минуты в 2 цифры
- s – секунды без лидирующего нуля
- ss – секунды в 2 цифры

Проблема с месяцами при замене MMMM,также заменяется например буква 'h' в 'March'- решена
Теперь проблема с заменой M и MM, заменяет без пробела. Между ними.Накосячил с заменой M наверное.

```js
function DateParse()
{
  var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  var month = document.getElementById('day').value;
  var day = document.getElementById('month').value;
  var hour = document.getElementById('hour').value;
  var minute = document.getElementById('min').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('sec').value;
  var mask = document.getElementById('mask').value;
  

  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  const monthNamesShort = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", 
  "Aug", "Sep", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];


  var masks =
  {
    yyyy : year,
    yy : year.substring(year.length/2,year.length),
    MMMM : monthNames[new Date(year,month,day).getMonth()] ,
    MMM : monthNamesShort[new Date(year,month,day).getMonth()],
    MM : month,
    M : month[1],
    dd : day,
    d : day[1],
    HH: new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute  + " PM").getHours(),
    H : new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute  + " PM").getHours()%10,
    hh :new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute  + " AM").getHours() ,
    h : new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute  + " AM").getHours()%10 ,
    mm : minute,
    m : minute[1],
    ss : second,
    s : second[1]
  }

  var res = mask;

  res = res.replace(/yyyy/g,masks.yyyy);
  res = res.replace(/yy/g,masks.yy);
  res = res.replace(/dd/g,masks.dd);
  res = res.replace(/d/g,masks.d);
  res = res.replace(/HH/g,masks.HH);
  res = res.replace(/H/g,masks.H);
  res = res.replace(/hh/g,masks.hh);
  res = res.replace(/h/g,masks.h);
  res = res.replace(/mm/g,masks.mm);
  res = res.replace(/m/g,masks.m);
  res = res.replace(/ss/g,masks.ss);
  res = res.replace(/s/g,masks.s);
  res = res.replace(/MMMM/g, masks.MMMM);
  res = res.replace(/MMM/g, masks.MMM);
  res = res.replace(/MM/g,masks.MM);
  res = res.replace(/M[\s\W]/g, masks.M);
  
  alert(res);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JS Basics</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JS Basics</h1>
    <p>Count Numbers</p>
    <form action="javascript:DateParse()">
    <input type="text" value="2015"  pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{3}$" maxlength="4" id = "year" placeholder="Year">
    <input type="text" value="02" pattern="[0-9]{2,}" maxlength="2" id="day" placeholder="Month">
    <input type="text" value="04" pattern="[0-9]{2,}" maxlength="2" id="month" placeholder="Day">
    <input type="text" value="05" pattern="[0-9]{2,}" maxlength="2" id="hour" placeholder="Hour">
    <input type="text" value="07" pattern="[0-9]{2,}" maxlength="2" id="min" placeholder="Minute">
    <input type="text" value="08" pattern="[0-9]{2,}" maxlength="2" id="sec" placeholder="Second">
    <input type="text" id ="mask" placeholder="Enter mask">
    <input type="submit" id="replace">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А пробовали сначала заменять всё, что заменяется на цифры, а потом уже MMM и MMMM?

Comment: @Darth нет,помогло)спасибо)

Comment: `[\s\W]` - этого тут вообще не должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что ты делаешь замены последовательно, а надо одновременно:

```js
console.log("ABX".replace(/A/g, "B").replace(/B/g, "C"))
console.log("ABX".replace(/A|B/g, m => ({A: "B", B: "C"}[m])))
```

Comment: Вы же мне утверждали обратное)

Comment: @AlexPark, ой.. действительно, что-то я наоборот ляпнул в прошлый раз. Сорри.

Comment: т.е. нужно использовать первый вариант?

Comment: @AlexPark, ну вроде нет? Вот же ответ с кодом, как можно.

Comment: при таком подходе всё правильно,только ещё изменяется при этом просто М, для этого я и использовал [\s\W],но он пробел ещё заменяет.

Comment: res = res.replace(/MMMM/g, masks.MMMM).replace(/MMM/g, masks.MMM).replace(/MM/g,masks.MM).replace(/M/g, masks.M);

Comment: @AlexPark, нет, наоборот. И не трожь другие символы.

Answer (score 0):

Чойта велосипедов захотелось (`Vue` чисто для вывода):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    date: new Date(),
    masks: {
      m: {
        title: 'Месяц без ведущего нуля (1-12)',
        value: d => d.getMonth() + 1 // Этот callback должен возвращать значение маски
      },
      mm: {
        title: 'Месяц с ведущим нулём (01-12)',
        value: d => (d.getMonth() + 1 + '').padStart(2, '0')
      },
      y: {
        title: 'Год, 4 цифры (2000)',
        value: d => d.getFullYear()
      }
    },
    input: 'This \\month: m, another \\month: mm, this \\year: y',
    result: ''
  },
  computed: {
    regexp: function () {
      return new RegExp(`(\\\\?)(${Object.keys(this.masks).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length).join('|')})`, 'g'); // Важно отсортировать от длинной к короткой строке маски, тогда вхождения будут корректно находится
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMe: function () {
      let input = this.input.trim();
      
      if(!input) return;
      
      this.result = input.replace(this.regexp, (_, s, m) => s ? m : m in this.masks && 'value' in this.masks[m] && typeof this.masks[m].value === 'function' ? this.masks[m].value(this.date) : `{${m}}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#result {
  margin: 10px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  Date: <strong>{{ date.toGMTString() }}</strong><br />
  Masks:
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(mask, key, i) in masks" :key="i"><span style='color: gray;'>{{ key }}</span>: {{ mask.title}}</li>
  </ul>
  Enter your mask here: <input type='text' autofocus v-model='input' @keyup.13='showMe' /><br />
  <div id='result'>{{ result }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну у меня тоже от длинной маски к короткой всё идет. И проблема ток с масками М и ММ.

Answer (score -1):

Для таких задач можно использовать библиотеку [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

К примеру преобразовать текущую дату в формат DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss будет выглядеть так:

```
moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

Любую другую дату в любом формате:

```
moment('2018-06-07 12-10-33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Это да,задание как раз таки написать велосипед)

Comment: А указать сей факт в вопросе вы не сочли нужным?